# Difference between item_collected_port and item_observed_port

Tags: uvm

Today I stumbled upon an old environment to find out that there is an "item_observed port" which is used to export to monitor's analysis port but here I am not getting response back from DUT if I use observed_port, I am not sure which version of UVM it uses because I only knew that there exists "item_collected port" which is used to export collected data to monitors analysis port from interface for coverage and other protocol checking.

Can anyone let me know what is the exact difference between item_observed_port vs item_collected_port and it would be better to name which version of UVM to use in "item_observed_port" case or if there any other alternate solutions available such as connecting 2 different ports for read and write (resp_rd_port or resp_wr_port) is also welcome.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with UVM itself. The analysis ports have no meaning for UVM. The semantics of what/when stuff gets sent out via analysis ports are defined by the UVC developer.

Comment: @TudorTimi I was wondering what is the use of item_observed_port instead of item_collected_port. I know the later can be used with UVM1.2, the main doubt here is, can former too can be used along with 1.2 or it needs an different method to use with the current version?

Comment: `item_collected_port` is not something that UVM defines. It's something that you define and assign which you assign a meaning.

Comment: ohh my bad understood now, uvm_analysis_port #(simple_item) item_collected_port;